# Not being able to modify a variable using two different threads in android using java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an integer variable which is "score". I have two different threads as I show:

Thread 1:

```
class Hilo1 extends Thread {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(30000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(Course.this, "SCORE="+score, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                

                            }
                        });
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thread 2:

```
class Hilo2 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(movementTimeThread);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(tranquilo(currentHeartRate,higherHeartRate,lowerHeartRate,changeInAcceleration)){
                                
                                score=score+1;

                                /*textViewPuntuacion.setText("Puntuacion= ");*/

                            }else {
                                vecesNoCalmado = vecesNoCalmado + 1;
                            }


                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    }
```

The situation  is the following: the first thread occurs every 30 seconds and it evaluates something. It that evaluation is true, the second threads starts 20 seconds after that and it increases the variable "score". The thing is that I have made sure that the evaluation is true so thread number 2 occurs and "score" is increased, but the next time thread number 1 occurs, "score" value is still 0. I don´t kniow what I´m doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you declare `score` and it is `volatile`? Also: does `tranquilo` ever return true? Is the line `score=score+1;` ever executed?

Comment: Thank you very much @f1sh for answering. I declare score at the beginning like this: public int score;. I have made sure that tranquilo returns true sometimes and that line is executed. I haven´t declared score as volatile? Would it be necessary?

Comment: You don't need to start threads just to sleep them. Use `postDelayed`. You also need to keep track of whatever you're starting so you can cancel it when the Activity or Fragment is destroyed. Otherwise you leak the whole Activity.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have tried using postDelayed with handler instead of thread 2 and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are both these threads inner classes of the class that has the `score` variable? You don't need to mark `score` as `volatile` since you are only touching it on the main thread.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thread 1 is inside the class that has score variable but the other one isn´t.

Comment: ...then it can't be looking at the same `score` variable, can it? Unless `score` is static and you have imported the member of the other class into the second Thread class's file.